# Spent like an hour trying to fix this I'm getting no where someone please help.. python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

w=Tk()
w.geometry('350x500')
w.title('Sunset Panel')
w.resizable(0,0)


#Making gradient frame
j=0
r=10
for i in range(100):
    c=str(222222+r)
    Frame(w,width=10,height=500,bg="#"+c).place(x=j,y=0)
    j=j+10
    r=r+1

Frame(w,width=250,height=400,bg='white').place(x=50,y=50)


l1=Label(w,text='Username',bg='white')
l=('Consolas',13)
l1.config(font=l)
l1.place(x=80,y=200)

#e1 entry for username entry
e1=Entry(w,width=20,border=0)
l=('Consolas',13)
e1.config(font=l)
e1.place(x=80,y=230)

#e2 entry for password entry
e2=Entry(w,width=20,border=0,show='*')
e2.config(font=l)
e2.place(x=80,y=310)


l2=Label(w,text='Password',bg='white')
l=('Consolas',13)
l2.config(font=l)
l2.place(x=80,y=280)


###lineframe on entry

Frame(w,width=180,height=2,bg='#141414').place(x=80,y=332)
Frame(w,width=180,height=2,bg='#141414').place(x=80,y=252)

from PIL import ImageTk,Image



imagea=Image.open("log.png")
imageb= ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagea)

label1 = Label(image=imageb,
               border=0,

               justify=CENTER)


label1.place(x=115, y=50)


#Command
def cmd():
    db = open("Data.txt", "r")
    Username = e1
    Password = e2
    if Username == e1:
        d = []
        f = []
        for i in db:
            a,b = i.split(", ")
            b = b.strip()
            d.append(a)
            f.append(b)
        data = dict(zip(d, f))
    if e1.get() == data[Username] and e2.get() == data[Password]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Login success", "Welcome")
        q=Tk()
        q.mainloop()

    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Login failed dumb ass","Try again goofy")


#Button_with hover effect
def bttn(x,y,text,ecolor,lcolor):
    def on_entera(e):
        myButton1['background'] = ecolor #ffcc66
        myButton1['foreground']= lcolor  #000d33

    def on_leavea(e):
        myButton1['background'] = lcolor
        myButton1['foreground']= ecolor

    myButton1 = Button(w,text=text,
                   width=20,
                   height=2,
                   fg=ecolor,
                   border=0,
                   bg=lcolor,
                   activeforeground=lcolor,
                   activebackground=ecolor,
                       command=cmd)

    myButton1.bind("<Enter>", on_entera)
    myButton1.bind("<Leave>", on_leavea)

    myButton1.place(x=x,y=y)


bttn(100,375,'L O G I N','white','#994422')


w.mainloop()
```

my error is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ezneu\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ezneu\OneDrive\Desktop\login\login.py", line 80, in cmd
    if e1.get() == data[Username] and e2.get() == data[Password]:
KeyError: <tkinter.Entry object .!entry>
```

sorry for the dumb question ive been at this all day and cant seem to figure out what the problem is I sent the entire code above if someone can correct! I keep getting the same "    KeyError: <tkinter.Entry object .!entry>" no clue what this means but I even watched a tutorial and my code was almost the same as the person in the tut yet there worked perfect please help!

Comment: `KeyError` means that `data[Username]` or `data[Password]` doesn't exist. That either means you haven't created the data, or `Username` and/or `Password` are not what you're assuming they are. My guess is the latter. Add `print(Username)` and I think you may be surprised at the result.

Comment: `Username` and `Password` are tkinter Entry widgets. They are not used as keys in `data`. The whole `cmd()` function is quite weird...

Answer (score 1):

Since `Username` is a reference to an `Entry` widget and `data` is a dictionary with string as the keys, so `data[Username]` will raise the exception.

Your checking should test whether `e1.get()` is a key in `data` and `e2.get()` should be equal to `data[e1.get()]`.

Below is the suggested modification of `cmd()`:

```py
def cmd():
    username = e1.get().strip()
    password = e2.get().strip()

    # both username and password have been input?
    if username and password:
        # load the credentials as a dictionary
        with open("Data.txt") as db:
            data = {}
            for i in db:
                a, b = i.split(", ")
                data[a] = b.strip()
        # check username and password
        if username in data and data[username] == password:
            messagebox.showinfo("Login Success", "Welcome")
            # do whatever you want if login successful
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Login Failed", "Try again")
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Invalid", "Please enter both username and password")
```

Answer (score 0):

https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/ :

A Python `KeyError` exception is what is raised when you try to access a key that isn’t in a dictionary ( in your case `data` ).

Here an example of content of the file 'Data.txt':

```
adam, a
bogdan, b
cicero, c
daniel, d
```

Below a making sense code of `cmd()` running without the error message:

```
def cmd():
    db = open("Data.txt", "r")
    d = []
    f = []
    for i in db.readlines():
        print (i)
        a, b = i.split(", ")
        b = b.strip()
        d.append(a)
        f.append(b)
    data = dict(zip(d, f))
    print(data)
    try:
        if data[e1.get()] == e2.get():
            messagebox.showinfo("Login success", "Welcome")
            q=Tk()
            q.mainloop()
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Wrong password entered", "Try again")
    except KeyError:
        messagebox.showwarning("Login failed dumb ass","Try again goofy")
```

And here entire code with the gradient frame which looks like it should:

```
from tkinter import *

w=Tk()
w.geometry('350x500')
w.title('Sunset Panel')
w.resizable(0,0)

#Making gradient frame
j=0; r=10
for _ in range(35):
    c=str(f'{155-r:02x}{255-r:02x}{155-r:02x}')
    print(c,end='|')
    Frame(w,width=10,height=500,bg="#"+c).place(x=j,y=0)
    j=j+10
    r=r+3

Frame(w,width=250,height=400,bg='white').place(x=50,y=50)
l1=Label(w,text='Username',bg='white')
l=('Consolas',13)
l1.config(font=l)
l1.place(x=80,y=200)

#e1 entry for username entry
e1=Entry(w,width=13,border=0)
l=('Consolas',13)
e1.config(font=l)
e1.place(x=80,y=230)

#e2 entry for password entry
e2=Entry(w,width=13,border=0,show='*')
e2.config(font=l)
e2.place(x=80,y=310)


l2=Label(w,text='Password',bg='white')
l=('Consolas',13)
l2.config(font=l)
l2.place(x=80,y=280)

###lineframe on entry
Frame(w,width=180,height=2,bg='#141414').place(x=80,y=332)
Frame(w,width=180,height=2,bg='#141414').place(x=80,y=252)

from PIL import ImageTk,Image
imagea=Image.open("log.png")
imageb= ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagea)

label1 = Label(image=imageb, border=0, justify=CENTER)
label1.place(x=115, y=50)
#Command
def cmd():
    db = open("Data.txt", "r")
    d = []
    f = []
    for i in db.readlines():
        print (i)
        a, b = i.split(", ")
        b = b.strip()
        d.append(a)
        f.append(b)
    data = dict(zip(d, f))
    print(data)
    try:
        if data[e1.get()] == e2.get():
            messagebox.showinfo("Login success", "Welcome")
            q=Tk()
            q.mainloop()
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Wrong password entered", "Try again")
    except KeyError:
        messagebox.showwarning("Login failed dumb ass","Try again goofy")


#Button_with hover effect
def bttn(x,y,text,ecolor,lcolor):
    def on_entera(e):
        myButton1['background'] = ecolor #ffcc66
        myButton1['foreground']= lcolor  #000d33

    def on_leavea(e):
        myButton1['background'] = lcolor
        myButton1['foreground']= ecolor

    myButton1 = Button(w,text=text,
                   width=20,
                   height=2,
                   fg=ecolor,
                   border=0,
                   bg=lcolor,
                   activeforeground=lcolor,
                   activebackground=ecolor,
                       command=cmd)

    myButton1.bind("<Enter>", on_entera)
    myButton1.bind("<Leave>", on_leavea)

    myButton1.place(x=x,y=y)

bttn(100,375,'L O G I N','white','#994422')


w.mainloop()
```